# Android studio stucked on creating a new project

Tags: android, android-studio

When I creating a new project in Android studio 3.1.3, I got stucked in the select SDK page. The selection area is grey. 
This is the second time I encounter this problem. The first time I sovled it by uninstall and reinstall Android studio few days ago, but this time it won't work.
[image: stuck in the sdk select tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's fetching and downloading something, just wait some minutes see what will happend

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's seems to be a network problem. I changed a new proxy, its all right now.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio works on a minimum of 3Gb RAM and additional 1 Gb is required if you are using AVD.
However Google recommends using 8Gb minimum RAM.
Check your configuration.